# Pyspark Window using dates as boundary

Tags: pyspark, window, boundary

I have a challenge in pyspark and I haven't really been able to find a good solution so far.

I need to sum values of six months for each line.

E.g.

Lets assume I have this:

| ID | DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-17 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2023-05-17 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2023-06-17 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2023-07-17 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2023-08-17 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2023-09-17 | 0.5 |
| 1 | 2023-10-17 | 2.0 |
| 1 | 2023-10-20 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 2023-04-17 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 2023-05-17 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 2023-06-17 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 2023-07-17 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 2023-08-17 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 2023-09-17 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 2023-10-17 | 2.0 |
| 2 | 2023-10-20 | 1.0 |

I need to create a sum column like that

| ID | DATE | VALUE | SUM(VALUE) | COMMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-17 | 1.0 | 1.0 | sum value only from month 04 from id 1 |
| 1 | 2023-05-17 | 1.0 | 2.0 | sum value from months 04, 05 from id 1 |
| 1 | 2023-06-17 | 1.0 | 3.0 | sum value from months 04, 05, 06 from id 1 |
| 1 | 2023-07-17 | 1.0 | 4.0 | sum value from months 04, 05, 06, 07 from id 1 |
| 1 | 2023-08-17 | 1.0 | 5.0 | sum value from months 04, 05, 06, 07, 08 from id 1 |
| 1 | 2023-09-17 | 0.5 | 5.5 | sum value from months 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09 from id 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-17 | 2.0 | 6.5 | sum value from months 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10 from id 1 |
| 1 | 2023-10-20 | 1.0 | 7.5 | sum value from months 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10 from id 1 |
| 2 | 2023-04-17 | 1.0 | 1.0 | sum value only from month 04 from id 2 |
| 2 | 2023-05-17 | 1.0 | 2.0 | sum value from months 04, 05 from id 2 |
| 2 | 2023-06-17 | 1.0 | 3.0 | sum value from months 04, 05, 06 from id 2 |
| 2 | 2023-07-17 | 1.0 | 4.0 | sum value from months 04, 05, 06, 07 from id 2 |
| 2 | 2023-08-17 | 1.0 | 5.0 | sum value from months 04, 05, 06, 07, 08 from id 2 |
| 2 | 2023-09-17 | 0.5 | 5.5 | sum value from months 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09 from id 2 |
| 2 | 2023-10-17 | 2.0 | 6.5 | sum value from months 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10 from id 2 |
| 2 | 2023-10-20 | 1.0 | 7.5 | sum value from months 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10 from id 2 |

I'v tried to use Window and rowsBetween/rangeBetween but I couldn't get the expected result

**EDIT:**
I can't show the real code as it contains some confidential information about the work, but I made these cells in Jupyter to test.

```py
data = [
    ['1', datetime(2024, 1, 1), 1.0],
    ['1', datetime(2023, 7, 1), 1.0],
    ['1', datetime(2023, 12, 1), 1.0],
    ['1', datetime(2023, 11, 1), 1.0],
    ['1', datetime(2023, 10, 1), 1.0],
    ['1', datetime(2023, 9, 15), 1.0],
    ['1', datetime(2023, 9, 16), 1.5],
    ['1', datetime(2023, 8, 17), 1.0],
    ['2', datetime(2023, 10, 1), 2.0],
    ['2', datetime(2023, 9, 7), 2.0],
    ['2', datetime(2023, 8, 20), 2.0]
    
]

header = ['id', 'data', 'valor']

rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, header)
df = df.withColumn('ano_mes', F.trunc(F.col('data'), 'month'))
df = df.withColumn('ano_mes', F.to_timestamp(F.col('data')))
df.show(truncate=False)

w = Window().partitionBy('id').orderBy('ano_mes').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

# here will sum all months by ID, but in this exemple, I need just the current month and last 2 by ID
df.withColumn('sum_valor', F.sum("valor").over(w)).show(truncate=False)
```

I managed to get the expected result using sql, but I'm still curious if there's something I can do in pyspark

Here is the code in SQL

```py
spark.sql("""
select *, sum(valor) over(
partition by id
order by ano_mes
range between interval 2 months PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as sum from df
""").show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Can you please explain the logic for `2023-10-17`  and `2023-10-20`?

Comment: Please add your code to your question so we can correct it.